# How to redirect to previous page on spring security access denied?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails and Spring Security. Some methods of the controller are annotated with `@Secured` and when the logged in user doesn't have the necessary roles I want him to be redirected to the last visited page instead of to `/login/denied`.

I guess that the real question is how to get the last page visited so that I can redirect him accordingly from the denied method?

There is a way to do this in JavaScript, using [back button](http://www.crowderassoc.com/javascript/backbutton.html), but I am looking for a way to achieve this on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use an `interceptor` to store the history of you views and then with an `accessDeniedHandler` redirect to the previous one